# Unable to PXE install with DVD Repo in Preseed

Tags: debian, drivers, system-installation, debian-installer, pxe

I have set up an nginx instance where it hosts the entirety of the DVD debian 11 iso file. This because I want to use it as a repo. It's unsigned, but the Release file and packages are there as it should be.

This with the objective of deploying debian 11 on several hosts via PXE in a closed network. Thing is, when I use my repo, it's unable to detect any disks on where to install.
Here's my preseed file:

```
d-i mirror/http/hostname string local.place.here:83
d-i mirror/http/directory string /debian/
d-i debian-installer/allow_unauthenticated boolean true(this because the DVD repo is unsigned, and I know I can sign, but not a priority at the moment)
```

If I do like so, I am greeted with the following error:
[image: No disks detected.]

While, if I change the preseed file to use the official Debian repos, it works fine.

```
d-i mirror/http/hostname string ftp.debian.org
d-i mirror/http/directory string /debian/
```

I've seen suggestions to create a new initrd.gz with the missing drivers, but that does not seem to be the case, because using the same initrd.gz it works on the official repos, so I suspect something is missing on the DVD, or some config file, in other for this to work.

This must be done on a closed network, and having limited space also, it's unfeasible to mirror the entirety of the Debian repo, hence the idea of using the DVD, and the DVD installs fine on its own in a host. The nginx instance does not seem to have any problem presenting the files, as I'm able to download files picked at random. So in sum, I'm not sure what's missing in order to have this to work.

Does anyone have any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try after including *di-utils-mapdevfs* package to your local repo?

I've resolved similar issue after checking logs on TTY4 while installing.
There error was unavailability of *di-utils-mapdevfs* package

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).